# Processing and Pipes

Tags: c++, process, pipe

Premise: Implement a C++ program that prompts the user for 2 commands. Each input string should be a UNIX command,  with arguments allowed. For example, input 1 could be "ls -l" and input 2 could be "wc -l".  The program will then create a pipe, and two child processes.  The first child process will run the command specified in the first input.  It will output to the pipe instead of standard output.  The second child process will run the command specified in the second input.  It will take its input from the pipe rather than standard input. 
The parent process will wait on its two children to complete,  then the whole thing will repeat.  Execution will stop when "quit" is entered as the first command.

I believe I am almost done with the program but I am getting having trouble figuring out how to get the user input executed in the pipe, and I end up with syntax errors.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //Declare Variables
    char first, second[80];
    int rs, pipefd[2];
    int pid1, pid2;
    char *command1[80], *command2[80];

    //Asking for the commands
    cout << "Please enter your first command(incl. args) or quit: ";
    cin >> first;

    //Do the program while the first answer isn't quit
    while(first[0] != 'quit') {

    //Copy first answer into first command
    strcpy(command1, ((char*)first);

    //Just skip to end of program if first command is quit
    cout << "Please enter your second command(incl. args): ";
    cin >> second;

    //Copy second answer into second command
    strcpy(command2, ((char*)first);

    //pipe
    rs = pipe(pipefd);
    //if pipe fails to be made
    if(rs == -1){
        perror("Fail to create a pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Fork for the two processes
    pid1 = fork();

    if (pid1 != 0){
    pid2 = fork();
}

    if(pid1 == -1){
        perror("Fail to create a pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
        if(pid2 == -1){
        perror("Fail to create a pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

        if (pid1 == 0) { // 1st child process   
        // close write end of pipe
        close(pipefd[0]);
        // duplicate
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
        //execute the input argument
        execvp(command1[0], command1);
    } 
                if (pid1 == 0) { // 2st child process   
        // close write end of pipe
        close(pipefd[0]);
        // duplicate
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
        //execute the input argument
        execvp(command2[0], command2);
    }

        else {  // parent process   
        // close read end of pipe
        close(pipefd[0]);
        // wait for child processes
        wait(&pid1);
        wait(&pid2);    
    }

    //Asking for the commands
    cout << "Please enter your first command(incl. args) or quit: ";
    cin >> first;

    }; //end of while()

return 0;
}
```

Any help/hints would be appreciated for this is due in the near future and I would love to finally have this beast tackled.

Edit: *Adding errors gotten*

```
In function int main()':
z1674058.cxx:26:33: error: expected ')' before ';' token
z1674058.cxx:33:33: error: expected ')' before ';' token
```

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation? It's haphazard and difficult to read.

Comment: Tip: When your code doesn't work, try to cut down the code until you reach something that shows the problem but is much less than the whole code. That way, you have much less code to work with. You can do this by "stubbing" out parts of the code (replacing it with something that produces the (or a valid) result, but doesn't do all the work.

Comment: Haha sorry Ben. I'll add the errors to the original post!

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you can't figure out why the compiler thinks there aren't enough `)` on those lines, I have very little hope for you solving difficult programming problems.

Comment: @BenVoigt Go easy on him, he is obviously a student, at least he has come here with some code rather than the regular: "Where can i find code to solve this problem?".

Comment: It was a silly mistake mate that I fixed up haha. Right now I've fixed some stuff up thanks to John K. but now after I try to input my first command after it compiles I get a segmentation fault. I'm very foreign to that word and could use some hints to finish this assignment up!

Comment: @Ben (the other one): Even students need to read the error message before asking for help on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// close write end of pipe
close(pipefd[0]);
// duplicate
dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
```

You have these same two lines in both child #1 and child #2. The two children should do opposite operations here. One of them should be closing `pipefd[1]` and duping `pipefd[0]` to stdin.

You've also got some string-handling bugs.

```
char first, second[80];
```

This doesn't declare two 80-character arrays. It declares one `char` and one `char[80]`. I suspect this is why you put in the `(char *)` cast here—to silence a compiler error:

```
strcpy(command1, ((char*)first);
```

Don't do that. Don't use casts to shut the compiler up. The cast is covering up a serious error.

```
char *command1[80], *command2[80];
```

These declarations are also incorrect. This declares two arrays of 80 `char *`s apiece. That is, two arrays containing 80 strings each. I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to fix this...

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have gotten farther, but I am still getting hung up on the strcpy @.@

Comment: If you `dup2()` a pipe to either 0 or 1, you need to close _both_ of the file descriptors returned by `pipe()`.  You do a lot of closes when you're using pipes.  And the parent process needs to close both ends of the pipe too.

Comment: Alright. So I think I closed up the pipes correctly this time and hopefully fixed the string and char bugs, but when I compile and run the program there is a segmentation fault after the first input.. Any ideas?

Comment: Your best bet is to run the program in a debugger like `gdb` which will tell you the exact line that's crashing and let you inspect variables live. Short of that, you can post another question. But if you do, do your best to eliminate all the code unrelated to the segfault and post as short a program as you can that still crashes. All the fork-related code is probably unrelated, for instance.

Comment: Good stuff man. I'm going to try and just ask another question relating to the bug I'm having. You've been very helpful, and I appreciate your time in helping me!